# Одно и двухстрочные подписи к плиткам бутстрап

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть набор кликабельных плиток бутстрап 3.х с фоновой картинкой:

```
<section id="category">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>Категории</h2>
        </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 encat">
                <div class="cat" style="background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/16:9x1080/');">
                    <a href="#">
                        <div>Юбка с рукавом Тринити макси облегающая</div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 encat">
                <div class="cat" style="background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/16:9x1080/');">
                    <a href="#">
                        <div>Юбка клёш</div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Каждая плитка имеет полупрозрачную полоску-подпись:

[image: однострочный вариант]

С этой подписью всё хорошо, пока надписи умещаются на мобильных устройствах в одну строку. Но беда в том, что половина надписей однострочные, а вторая половина -- из двух строк.

[image: варианты разрывов]

Как ни пробую - либо получается, что двухстрочные подписи выглядят нормально, а однострочные уползают вверх (вариант справа на скриншоте), либо однострочные выглядят нормально, а двустрочные налезают на следующую плитку (вариант слева на скриншоте). А так, чтобы одновременно было хорошо -- не понимаю, за какой параметр ухватиться, чтобы рассчитать.

Интересует как конкретный код, так и пояснения внутреннего устройства.

PS Мой набор стилей:

```
#category .encat {
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

#category .cat {
    height:200px;
    background-size:cover;
}

#category .encat a {
    line-height:18px;
    height:200px;
    display:block;
    font-size:18px;
    width:100%;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}

#category .encat a div {
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:140px;
    height:30;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

@media(min-width:992px) {

#category .cat {
    height:300px;
}

#category .encat a {
    line-height:30px;
    height:300px;
    font-size:18px;
}

#category .encat a div {
    left:0px;
    top:250px;
    height:30;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}

}
```

Comment: как вариант использовать для text - position: absolute; bottom: 0; - пример - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/fawbygh9/2/

Comment: @soledar10 Выглядит, как то, что нужно. А почему в комментах, а не в ответе?

Comment: @A K - добавил ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант использовать для text - `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cat {
    display: block; /* делаем ссылку блочным элементом */
    height: 200px;
    background: #ccc;
    position: relative; /* задаем родителю значение position relative, чтобы отсчет координат ввелся от края родительского элемента для child с position: absolute */
    margin: 15px 0;
}

.cat-caption {
    position: absolute; /* позиционируем блок с тектом */
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
    transition: .3s;
}

.cat:hover .cat-caption {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <a href="#" class="cat">
                <div class="cat-caption">
                    text
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <a href="#" class="cat">
                <div class="cat-caption">
                    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <a href="#" class="cat">
                <div class="cat-caption">
                    text
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ответ верный уже дали, оставлю просто с пояснениями и без изменения разметки (хотя могу ошибаться, так как не знаю бутстрап, но главное логику подобных штук проследить по комментариям)

```
@media(min-width:992px) {
  #category .cat {
    position: relative; // задается, что бы дети с абсолютным позиционированием ориентировались на параметры этого родителя
    height:300px;
  }

  #category .encat a {
    // Растягиваем ссылку на всю ширину и высоту родителя (.cat)
    display: block;
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    // закончили растягивать
    line-height:30px;
    height:300px;
    font-size:18px;
  }

  #category .encat a div {
    // текст позиционируем внизу родительского блока (<a>), высота остается auto, блок прижимается к левому нижнему углу и растягивается на всю ширину родителя 
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    // Закончили позиционировать и растягивать
    padding: 10px 5px;
  }
}
```